# Font in XML with Android O

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

Android O give font directory with new android-studio version 3.0 but when in drop font-file in font directory and run project it give me a error in font file in font directory.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> /home/ttuser4/Downloads/fontPractice/app/src/main/res/font/Dancing_Script.ttf: Error: The file name must end with .xml

Comment: You can clearly see the error. You will get whats the problem.

Comment: error said that file extension in font directory should be .xml but how a font file have extension .xml

Comment: according to https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html   we can add normal font file in font directory. they are doing so.

Comment: **ALL** resource names only allow these characters: `a...z_.0...9`. Fonts included.

Comment: The issue is with the version of gradle plugin, Android plugin and support library versions. Make sure you are aligned to below config:

1. You need to have Android Studio 3.0+ and Android SDK 8.0 (API 26+)

2. Gradle plugin version 3.0.0-beta4 or higher and Android plugin version 4.1 is required

3. It is recommended to have support library version 25.0+ in order to see the preview of fonts in studio

Answer (score 13):

I also got the similar issue. To fix that i followed the below steps.

1. Updated Android Studio to latest canary build.
2. Change `distributionUrl` in `project-dir/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` to latest gradle distribution url(You can get the latest availability of gradle from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)) to update the gradle version used to build like below.

   > distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
3. Then update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version in the root `build.gradle` to the latest like below. (Note: Below mentioned version is the latest one when the answer is posted. The version might be change in future. So take care about that.)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

4. Sync, Clean and update the project.

It worked for me. Let me know with your comments.

Comment: Note that this will fail if you're not using Android Studio 3.0

Comment: @teffi As the question denoted the user is getting issue with Android Studio 3.0. So the answer is written based on that.

Comment: this answer worked for me using AS3 + full clean + rebuild, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using an older build tools plugin, so it does not know about res/font and the new font capabilities.

I had the same problem I update to gradle build tools 2.4.0-alpha7

but I got an error message on build and then had to set environment variable

```
launchctl setenv ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE <your-value-on-error-message>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have opened your Android Studio Project.

1. Right click on `res` directory, and select `New > Android Resource Directory`.
2. Select resource directory "font".

[image]

3. Change your font name to "dancing.ttf" (capitalized names generate error). I used "Pacifico-Font" and got the following error message -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>       res/font/Pacifico-Font.ttf: Error: 'P' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only
>   lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

When I changed it to `pacifico.ttf`, it worked.

4. Add the font to the fonts folder.
5. Run your app.

I've followed the exact same steps on the Android Studio 3.0 Preview with "pacifico.ttf" font, and it works for me.

[image]

In case you encounter any errors, clean project once and then run it again.

Do let me know if you still run into issues.

Comment: These steps doesn't help. May be you should try once again.

Comment: Where did you get an error this time ? At which step particularly?

Comment: I am able to see the change in the font on the preview in the layout design but when I run it on my phone, the font is back to default and I get messages that build gradle cannot find font, fontstyle, fontweight. Could you perhaps share the gradle settings as well ?

Comment: Are you running Android O on your phone ? Because only that OS supports these fonts. Android has released a support library for the same to support lower versions, check them out [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/fonts-revisited/)

Comment: `.../app/src/main/res/font/fontname.ttf: Error: The file name must end with .xml` - it doesn't works

Answer (score -2):

You can add  font in any format, but you have to create a `Font Family` xml file in order to apply these fonts in xml layout file. A font family is an XML file that contains multiple font files along with its style and weight details. You can access the font family as a single unit.

To create a font family, perform the following steps in the Android Studio:

1. Right-click the font folder and go to New > Font resource file. The New Resource File window appears.
2. Enter the file name, and then click OK. The new font resource XML opens in the editor.
3. Enclose each font file, style, and weight attribute in the  element. The following XML illustrates adding font-related attributes in the font resource XML:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <font
           android:fontStyle="normal"
           android:fontWeight="400"
           android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
       <font
           android:fontStyle="italic"
           android:fontWeight="400"
           android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
   </font-family>
   ```

Then you can add this font-family to any element in layout containing text. Like in this example its applying to `TextView`,

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```