# how can fixed this font_subtitle.otf

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

how a can fixed Error:Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: my problem is https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIin6.png

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the fact that you have put a file of type `.otf` into a folder than only accepts `.xml` or `.png` (`res/drawable` is a folder you only put pictures and drawable resource files into).

Put that `font_subtitle.otf` file into a fonts folder. Your fonts folder should already be made for you in app -> src -> main -> assets -> fonts. But if not just make one and put your file in there.

Also, I assume that you might not know how to use the file once it is in your assets folder, so I will just include some code showing an example of how to use the file.

```
Typeface eightBitFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/custom.TTF");
topText.setTypeface(eightBitFont);
```

In this example, I create a `Typeface` object and create a custom font from my file. I then use my `topText` object (which is a `TextView`) and set the type face using `setTypeface` and use the name I gave my object in the line before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the new [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) feature added to Android O - 8.0 (API 26), you definitely can add font files (.ttf, .ttc or .otf) to the \res\font folder.

You probably need to upgrade to Android Studio 3.+ and build tools 3+ to get it to compile properly without the error.

Also, take a look at this post: [Font in XML with Android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560908/font-in-xml-with-android-o)